# CSS cursor for ancient versions of Chrome

Tags: css, cursor

```
.title {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

In ancient versions of Chrome (ver 34 or similar, on Win XP) this doesn't work. Cursor is displayed as edit.

Is it possible to have any arrow cursor in older versions?

I checked `https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-cursors` - but didn't find the answer.

Comment: you can have any svg cursors

Comment: @MisterJojo, any example, pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample code for SVG custom cursor:

```js
var myCursor = `url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' `;
    myCursor += `x='0px' y='0px' width='16px' height='16px' viewbox='0 0 16 16' fill='%231278b8' %3E`;
    myCursor += `%3Cpath d='M0,0h6l-6,6z' /%3E%3Cpath d='M16,0h-6l6,6z' /%3E%3Cpath d='M0,16h6l-6,-6z' /%3E`;
    myCursor += `%3Cpath d='M16,16h-6l6,-6z' /%3E%3Ccircle cx='8' cy='8' r='4.4' stroke='%23231F20' `;
    myCursor += `stroke-width='1' fill='transparent' /%3E%3C/svg%3E") 7 7, pointer`;

document.getElementById('myDiv').style.cursor = myCursor;
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" >xxx</div>
```